# How do I plot my data through in discrete time bins?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a series of scatterplots (x=PC1, y=PC2) for a bunch of data I have collected. I am having issues plotting the data through time, specifically, automating the creation of plots relative to specific time bins. I have hundreds of entries and I already wasted too much time trying to divide the dataset manually.

The data has been collected similarly to this example:

| SPECIES | GROUP | APPEARANCE | DISAPPEARANCE | PC1 | PC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | A | 1 | 2 | -0.100119669 | 0.0595756 |
| Beta | B | 1 | 2 | 0.217854357 | -0.010260947 |
| Gamma | B | 1 | 5 | 0.193998962 | -0.029757206 |
| Delta | B | 2 | 3 | 0.126089613 | 0.014409345 |
| Epsilon | D | 3 | 4 | -0.094182811 | -0.004406088 |

Here we assume that each time bin lasts 1 unit (i.e.  a species appears at time 1 and disappears at time 2). As you see, some species last longer than others, thus belonging to multiple time bins.

I have tried all that my beginner knowledge allowed me to conjure and searched for an answer on the internet,  but I am still very much a pen-and-paper scientist. I really need some help with this.

I have tried all that my beginner knowledge allowed me to conjure and searched for an answer on the internet.

Comment: Perhaps an example of desired output would help here. Stumbled on a cross-post in Reddit where you seem to look for a way to generate and save a series of individual plots, one for each time bin. Having it included in the question makes it much easier for others to understand the actual problem. E.g. I was pretty sure it's about visualisation approach and ggplot faceting.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a more straightforward approach, but this achieves what you want using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The workflow is:

1. Create 'dummy' variable "APPEARED" with all == 1. This is to ensure only one instance of "APPEARANCE" is created by `slice(rep())`
2. Pivot to long form and create a new row for each time unit
3. Create "time_var" column to hold "APPEARANCE" value and sequential value for time units in existence
4. Filter any "DISAPPEARANCE" values < "APPEARANCE" values

I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle the time units that are neither the first nor last time unit for each group so I've arbitrarily identified them as "EXISTED".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Sample data
df <- read.table(text = "SPECIES    GROUP   APPEARANCE  DISAPPEARANCE   PC1     PC2
Alpha   A   1   2   -0.100119669    0.0595756
Beta    B   1   2   0.217854357     -0.010260947
Gamma   B   1   5   0.193998962     -0.029757206
Delta   B   2   3   0.126089613     0.014409345
Epsilon     D   3   4   -0.094182811    -0.004406088", header = TRUE)

test <- df %>%
  mutate(APPEARED = 1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(SPECIES, GROUP, APPEARANCE, PC1, PC2),
               names_to = "status") %>%
  group_by(SPECIES, status) %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = value)) %>%
  mutate(time_var = 1:n(),
         time_var = ifelse(status == "APPEARED", APPEARANCE, time_var)) %>%
  group_by(SPECIES) %>%
  mutate(tmp = first(time_var)) %>%
  filter(time_var > tmp | status == "APPEARED") %>%
  mutate(status = ifelse(status == "DISAPPEARANCE" & time_var == max(time_var),
                       "DISAPPEARED",
                       ifelse(status == "APPEARED", 'APPEARED', "EXISTED"))) %>%
  select(-c(APPEARANCE, value, tmp)) %>%
  ungroup()

data.frame(test)
   SPECIES GROUP         PC1          PC2      status time_var
1    Alpha     A -0.10011967  0.059575600    APPEARED        1
2    Alpha     A -0.10011967  0.059575600 DISAPPEARED        2
3     Beta     B  0.21785436 -0.010260947    APPEARED        1
4     Beta     B  0.21785436 -0.010260947 DISAPPEARED        2
5    Delta     B  0.12608961  0.014409345    APPEARED        2
6    Delta     B  0.12608961  0.014409345 DISAPPEARED        3
7  Epsilon     D -0.09418281 -0.004406088    APPEARED        3
8  Epsilon     D -0.09418281 -0.004406088 DISAPPEARED        4
9    Gamma     B  0.19399896 -0.029757206    APPEARED        1
10   Gamma     B  0.19399896 -0.029757206     EXISTED        2
11   Gamma     B  0.19399896 -0.029757206     EXISTED        3
12   Gamma     B  0.19399896 -0.029757206     EXISTED        4
13   Gamma     B  0.19399896 -0.029757206 DISAPPEARED        5
```